# Remove an object in NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray like this:

```
NSMutableArray *array =...; (array contain my custom object)
NSMutableArray *toRemove = [array getObjectsToRemove];
```

But when I try to call removeObjectsInArray ( [array removeObjectsInArray:toRemove]; ) it breaks my app! Can anybody tell me how to solve my problem :(

Comment: It just break my app :( I have little time to work with iOS. :)

Comment: What is `getObjectsToRemove`?

Comment: It's my custom methods. It just get some object from array.

Comment: I don't believe your app will break without an error message. Check the debug log and see what's there.

Comment: Also post the code for `getObjectsToRemove`. We have no way of knowing what it's doing. How did you create `getObjectsToRemove`? Are you aware that it's Bad™ to subclass `NSMutableArray` (because it is a class cluster)?

Comment: Go to Run->Console and see what's the error message.

Answer (score 3):

I expect the error you are getting is "[NSMutableArray getObjectsToRemove] unrecognized selector sent to.."

NSMutableArray does not have such a method.

That's as far as I can answer without a bit more information, like the actual error message and the code for getObjectsToRemove (wherever it is defined).